# Firebase push activity intent not cleaning

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app received push message(**notification** type) and Firebase automatically displays it. 
When I click on this push message app opens **MainActivity** and I have some extras in **Intent**, like this:

[image]

Then I close or force stop the app and start from the icon and I'm getting the same result as on screenshot.

I have tried `setIntent(null)` and `getIntent().replaceExtras(Bundle.EMPTY)` but it didn't help.

By the way, here is JSON that I'm sending to FCM:

```
{
   "to":"DEVICE_TOKEN",
   "notification":{
      "title":"SOME_TITLE",
      "body":"SOME_BODY"
   }
}
```

How I can clear this **extras** or **Intent**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's because the notification is generated by Firebase. Try to receive the FCM message and create the notification programatically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: *Juan Cruz Soler*, I know that and when I use data notification it works as I expect. But I'm just wondering if I can handle this case also?

Comment: I don't think that you can customize how the default Firebase notification works